# ionic @ionic-native/geolocation add provider issue

Tags: geolocation, ionic4

> Type 'GeolocationOriginal' is not assignable to type 'Provider'. Type
>   'GeolocationOriginal' is missing the following properties from type
>   'FactoryProvider': provide, useFactory

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation#usage

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the import code.

```
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
```

to

```
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';
```

// For ionic 4

Comment: Is it a solution for ionic 3?