# ionic 5 @ionic-native/geolocation add provider issue

Tags: geolocation, ionic5

I still encoumter this error despite follow the thread

[ionic @ionic-native/geolocation add provider issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55567581/ionic-ionic-native-geolocation-add-provider-issue)

> Type 'GeolocationOriginal' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.
> Type 'GeolocationOriginal' is missing the following properties from type 'FactoryProvider': provide, useFactoryts(2322)

My code has as below.

```js
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';
```

Comment: anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

The above error flagged from **app.module.ts**.

I manage to solve this by Added import script in **app.component.ts**

```
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';
```

Comment: Thanks it solved my Issue, Can you explain why it works?